# Problem with Stokes' theorem: how can I apply it?

Tags: differential-geometry, stokes-theorem

Let $\gamma$ be a smooth curve in $M:= \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ very close to the origin that goes once around the origin and assume that the image of $\gamma$, which we denote by $N$, is a submanifold of $M$. Endow $N$ with the counterclockwise orientation. Compute $\int_N i^* \alpha$ where $\alpha = \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2 + y^2}$ and $i: N \to M$ is the inclusion.

Attempt: Not entirely sure how to begin. I'm sure I must apply Stokes' somehow, but I'm not sure how. Maybe I will need to add some extra cirkles or something like that.

Comment: We are to endow the completely mysterious symbol $N$ with a specific orientation.  What sort of thing is $N$ that is being so endowed?

Comment: I'm guessing it's the image of $\gamma$ thought of as a submanifold of $M$.

Comment: Yes, I edited the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $\gamma$ is a smooth, closed non-self-intersecting curve, given the standard orientation, then $\int_N i^* \alpha$ is just integration over the image of $\gamma$. And since $0\notin \text{im}\ \gamma$, compactness of $\text{im}\ \gamma$ gives us an $r>0$ such that $C\subseteq  \text{im}\ \gamma$ where $C=\{(x,y)=(r\cos t,r\sin t):0\le t<2\pi \}.$ And now Green's theorem says $\int_N i^* \alpha=\int_Ci^*\alpha=2\pi.$

Answer (score 0):

Since $N$ is just the image of $\gamma$, we can compute the integral over $N$ via a parameterization using $\gamma$. For our parameterization, use $\gamma(t) = (x(t),y(t))= (\cos(t),\sin(t))$ for $t\in[0,2\pi)$. Noting that $x(t)^2+y(t)^2 = 1$, we then compute the pullback:
$$
i^*\alpha = i^*\left(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy\right) = i^*\left(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\right)i^*(dx)+i^*\left(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right)i^*(dy) \\= -\sin t\cdot d(\cos(t))+\cos t\cdot d(\sin(t)) = \sin^2t+\cos^2t=1.
$$
Therefore, $$\int_Ni^*\alpha = \int_0^{2\pi}1dt = 2\pi.$$

Comment: Right, but it is not given that the image of $\gamma$ is a circle?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. The proof of the general fact is a lot more technical and it depends on what specific tools you have already learned about in your class. Section 5.7-A of Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces by Manfredo Do Carmo does a nice job of this

Comment: I'll check it out! Thanks.

Comment: If by "very close to the origin that goes once around the origin " you mean a non-self-intersecting smooth closed curve, then it is homotopic to the curve $t\mapsto (r\cos t,r\sin t)$ for suitable $r$ and since $\int_Ni^*\alpha$ is basically the winding number of $\gamma$, you can indeed just integrate over the circle

Comment: That's why I specified "depends on what specific tools you have already learned." Showing things are homotopic to a circle makes things easy but some treatments of the subject avoid this topological language

Comment: Yes, it's a lot of overkill. Ugh since everything is smooth, you can just use Green's theorem in the plane. Either way, you get your answer.

Comment: Doesn't Green's theorem specifically not work in this case because of the hole in the domain and the singularity in the differential form? This question is essentially asking you to show the the winding number of any simple closed curve containing the origin is $\pm1$, which requires a lot of work either in just computation or in topological prerequisites

Comment: Green's theorem applied to the region bounded by $im \ \gamma$ and $C$ (in my answer) says that the integral over the  cycle $im\ \gamma -C$ is zero.

Comment: ah that's a good way to do it